# How to find frequency with only amplitude?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, frequency

I came across the following problem earlier.

> A platform oscillates in the vertical direction with simple harmonic motion. It’s amplitude of oscillation is C. What is the range of frequency of oscillation for a mass placed on the platform to remain in contact with the platform?"

It seems like I have to calculate the frequency given only the amplitude. But I don't understand how this is mathematically possible! I must be missing something - has anyone got a hint about whether I've misunderstood the physics?

Comment: You aren't being asked to calculate the frequency. You're being asked to calculate the *maximum* frequency that allows the mass to stay on the platform i.e. the acceleration of the platform must be less than $g$.

Comment: For the record, please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Aha, apologies I felt by stating explicitly that I didn't want answers that it was ok. I'll have a look at that post now :) Feel free to lock the question if you want.

Comment: Oh and thanks for the pointing in the right direction. I was misunderstanding the question it seems!

Comment: I think that this question shouldn't be closed because it highlights a genuine physical misunderstanding, and as such is interesting. Also tpg2114 has given a good answer which explains the concept well, without providing a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a ball in your hand and you hold your hand flat. You then move your arm rapidly 0.5 m upwards. The ball flies up and out of your hand.

Now repeat the experiment, but this time, move your hand very slowly so it takes, say, 10 seconds to move that 0.5 m upwards. The ball doesn't move out of your hand at all.

So what does this mean? Two experiments, identical amplitudes, and in one case the ball left your hand and in the other it did not. The rate at which you reach the amplitude is what matters.

Why does it matter? What forces act on the ball throughout the movement of your hand? How do the frequency and amplitude of simple harmonic motion relate to the velocity and acceleration of the your hand? And how does that relate to the forces and acceleration of the ball?